# Play flac file with Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, flac

I have to play a flac file with `Appcelerator`. Is it possible in any way?

I tried searching for `modules` and I also tried to play the file with `Ti.Media.AudioPlayer`. But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I resolved it using `Hyperloop`and the `OrigamiEngine` framework